# JBoss Authentication Question(s)

Tags: java, authentication, jboss

I have a three-part question related to JBoss 5 Authentication (in the Web/EJB containers):

1. Is there a way to propogate an
   identity other than the username
   that was specified during login? For
   example, using the
   DatabaseServerLoginModule, I want to
   authenticate the user with a
   username/password but return the
   user's id, and not username, when
   ejbContext.getCallerPrincipal() or
   httpRequest.getUserPrincipal() is
   called.
2. Even better, I want to make a custom
   login module which returns a User
   object (probably an entity which was
   loaded from the database). However,
   even if I wrap that User object up
   nicely in a Principal subclass in my
   login module, the EJB-layer never
   gets that object. Instead, the
   EJB-layer always gets a
   SimplePrincipal when
   getCallerPrincipal is called.
3. I want to be able to trigger a login
   programmatically, as described in
   [WebAuthentication](http://www.jboss.org/community/wiki/WebAuthentication). However, I need
   to do this without knowing the
   password. Imagine a customer service
   interface where a customer service
   agent can login to the application
   as an end-user. They would click a
   "login-as" button and we should be
   able to programmatically log them in
   as a user, without ever knowing the
   user's password (the customer
   service agent is already
   authenticated himself). You could
   also have this same scenario with
   "forgot password" which uses an
   alternate login mechanism to
   authenticate the user and then
   programatically logs them in.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question from two years ago: since the time I wrote this question, we've switched over to Spring Security and found it to be much more flexible than what's available in JBoss alone. My recommendation to anyone looking for a real solution to this problem is to give up on the container-provided authentication and take a good look at Spring Security.

Answer (score 0):

1) Not that familiar with the DatabaseServerLoginModule but shouldn't the user's id also be their username?  Usernames should be unique at least?

(Well after reading the  rest of your question maybe this is not helpful...)